# Is there a way of using changebars with XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex

Is there any way of using the `changebars` package with XeLaTeX?

The current release of `changebars` doesn't support a `xetex` option.  Almost three years ago there was [a discussion on comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.text.tex/867CO2Sj0dQ/discussion) about a patch to the package to support XeTeX, but nothing seems to have come of it; there was a similar question [on the xetex mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2011-January/019820.html) last year, which seems to have gone unanswered.

Is there a recommended alternative to the `changebars` package which works with XeTeX, or any samizdat patches to it floating around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regrettably, `changebar` uses its own driver code and doesn't have any for `dvipdfm` or related drivers, which includes `xdvipdfmx`, used by XeTeX. As such, the answer here is 'no'.

Comment: Has anyone incorporated the changes from Rocky Zhang mentioned at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/867CO2Sj0dQ If not, where could one access his patch?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve a similar effect using the `mdframed` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0sp}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    leftmargin=-11pt,
    linewidth=1pt
]{changebars}

\begin{document}

    In London, also, on Saturday night there was a thunderstorm, and my brother reached Waterloo in a cab. 

    \begin{changebars}
        On the platform from which the midnight train usually starts he learned, after some waiting, that an accident prevented trains from reaching Woking that night. 
    \end{changebars}

    The nature of the accident he could not ascertain; indeed, the railway authorities did not clearly know at that time.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

- As of today, Dec 31, 2018, the changebar package now supports a `xetex` driver
- Prior to this (and after the time the last few answers here were posted), a dedicated package for this very same purpose [`xechangebar`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xechangebar) was available.

Comment: However, it seems that `\cbcolor` dose not work in `xechangebar`. And `\changebarsep`  of package `changebar` does not work when changebar across pages .