# XeLaTeX and the changbar package

Tags: xetex, packages, mdframed, changebar

Does anyone know if there has been an update to changebar or a workaround that will get it to work with XeLaTeX? I found two conversations from years ago about the topic but have not found anything recent. [One on StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82406/is-there-a-way-of-using-changebars-with-xelatex) and one on a [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/867CO2Sj0dQ/discussion) message board.

I have tried using the mdframed package with this code:

```
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    leftmargin=-11pt,
    linewidth=1pt
]{changebars}
```

But unfortunately it creates a space between the sections so if only a couple of sentences changed in a paragraph they get separated by space.
Any ideas? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changebar}

\begin{document}

Does anyone know if there has been an update to changebar or a workaround
that will get it to work with XeLaTeX? I found two conversations from years
ago about the topic but have not found anything recent. One on StackExchange
and one on a Google Groups message board. Does anyone know if there has
been an update to changebar or a workaround that will get it to work with
XeLaTeX? I found two conversations from years ago about the topic but have
not found anything recent. One on StackExchange and one on a Google Groups
message board. Does anyone know if there has been an update to changebar or
a workaround that will get it to work with XeLaTeX? I found two
conversations from years ago about the topic but have not found anything
recent. \cbstart One on StackExchange and one on a Google Groups message
board. Does anyone know if there has been an update to changebar or a
workaround that will get it to work with XeLaTeX? \cbend I found two
conversations from years ago about the topic but have not found anything
recent. One on StackExchange and one on a Google Groups message board.
Does anyone know if there has been an update to changebar or a workaround
that will get it to work with XeLaTeX? I found two conversations from years
ago about the topic but have not found anything recent. One on StackExchange
and one on a Google Groups message board.

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** It works with LuaLaTeX, so I switched to that.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added to the question a complete small document using changebar and say what doesn't work in xetex

Comment: I updated the original post with a basic document using changbar. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes thanks, I just made it not all on one line:-)